# Implementing Comments with React Native and Node.js with user

Tags: node.js, react-native

how to show the user name of a person who has posted this comment in react native. Currently, I am able to fetch text from the database but don't know how to get user details who posted it.

**This is my Nodejs post:**

```
[{"_id":"5e4e2bb56a6a71f0c9f366b3","text":"testing is for nodejs and mongodb is fetching by user id v2","user":[]}]
```

**post.js post model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const slug = require("slug");
// const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");
// const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    text: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    slug: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      lowercase: true
    },
    user: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
      }
    ]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

PostSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  this._slugify();
  next();
});

PostSchema.methods = {
  _slugify: function() {
    this.slug = slug(this.text);
  },
  toJSON() {
    return {
      _id: this._id,
      text: this.text,
      slug: this.slug,
      user: this.user
    };
  }
};

PostSchema.statics = {
  createPost(args, user) {
    return this.create({
      ...args,
      user
    });
  }
  // list({ skip = 0, limit = 10 } = {}) {
  //   return this.find()
  //     .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
  //     .skip(skip)
  //     .limit(limit)
  //     .populate("user");
  // }
};

mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

**post.js React native**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Text, View, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import stylesheet from '../src/styles/FeedsStyle';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const FeedScreen = props => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('loading');


  const Boiler = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    fetch('http://192.168.1.2:3000/post', {
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      }),
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        // console.log(data);
        // // console.log(data.us);
        console.log(data);
        setUser(data);
        setText(data);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    Boiler();
  }, []);

  if (text == 'loading') {
    return (
      <View style={stylesheet.container}>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={stylesheet.container}>
        {/* {text.map(item => {
          return <Text>{item.text}</Text>;
        })} */}

        <FlatList
          style={stylesheet.productBox}
          data={text}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
              <View style={stylesheet.flatview}>
                <Text style={stylesheet.name}>{item.text}</Text>
                <Text style={stylesheet.name}>2nd value: </Text>
              </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default FeedScreen;
```

Comment: I think you need extra query to fetch user details. Post object holds user's id. You must access this an query it on user scheme.

Comment: can  you help me how to do it ?

Comment: can you share your postController in api (i am not sure name)